# Git diff doesn't do anything

Tags: git, diff

I'm trying to find the new/changed file list on the remote branch, when it is the newer one. My local machine (not really local, but an ssh-accessed machine) needs to be updated and I need the list of files to update.

I was hoping to loop through `git diff --name-only`, but they never output anything.

```
root@machine-name:/var/www/stuff# git diff
root@machine-name:/var/www/stuff#
```

See? Nothing. I tried combinations of...

```
git diff master
git diff HEAD
git diff ...master
git status -v
```

But still, nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing two commits between which you need a diff, like so:

```
git diff remote_branch/master master
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. `git diff --name-only origin/master master` was what I needed.